# Why does a figure capture a whole page?

Tags: floats, two-column

I have a figure in a whole page, even though I do not intend it to capture a whole page. There is a lot of white space around it, and I definitely think there could be some text surrounding it. Is there a way to force a figure not to use a whole page if there is still some white space around?

(this is a two column document, if that helps. I am using figure* to stretch the figure across the two columns.)

Comment: As always a minimal example or at least more information about the used class and packages would be very helpful. See again [this question of yours](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11366/how-can-i-get-the-figures-not-to-be-pushed-to-the-end-of-the-document/11382#11382) for adjusting the placement relevant settings for floats (`figure`, `table`).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- By default, full-width figures are only allowed at the top or at float pages, which obiously is the case for you. Try to solve it using placement options, such as

  `\begin{figure}[!ht]`
- Bottom placement is possible using the [`stfloats`](http://ctan.org/pkg/stfloats) package. Further you might have a look at [Placing two-column floats at bottom of page](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-2colfloat) in the TeX FAQ.
- Ensure that the figure is not too wide. Check if there's white space, if the figure has a margin. This is sometimes overlooked when PDF figures are included.
- Check for warnings regarding an overfull `\hbox` concerning that figure, which may cause that it's been deferred to the next page. If necessary, scale the figure.

Comment: Note: if the figure is to wide wrap its *content* (not the whole `figure` environment) in a `\makebox[h]{\textwidth}{...}` macro call. This makes it officially only `\textwidth` wide and centers it.

Comment: @MartinScharrer That doesn't seem to work when the content is an `equation` or `gather` or any math environment. What should I do in that case?

Comment: @Bakuriu: For such environments (which require a paragraph and don't work in the *restricted horizontal mode* created by `\makebox`) use a `{minipage}{\textwidth}` environment instead.