# Large table is placed on extra page

Tags: floats, positioning

I am using LaTeX, and I have a large table in my report, the height of table is a little more than half of the paper. all the text after the table will go to the next page, and in this page just the table remain and a lot of space after and before the table!

Comment: Hi mary, welcome to TeX.SX, the stack exchange site for TeX, LaTeX and friends. Your question was migrated here and I adjusted the title to better fit to the page.

Comment: How exactly are you coding the table? Are you using the normal approach of a `tabular` inside a `table` environment or something different?

Answer (score 5):

Your table is too large to fit onto a normal page of text and is therefore placed on a "float page", i.e. a page which only contains material from `table` and `figure` (or custom defined) float environments.

If you want to place such a large table on a normal page you can either modify the appropriate settings (see [How can I get the figures not to be pushed to the end of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11366/how-can-i-get-the-figures-not-to-be-pushed-to-the-end-of-the-document/11382#11382)). Increasing the `\floatpagefraction` already mentioned by Forrest  allows larger tables on normal text pages. It states which fraction of the page a table or figure can consume before placed on an extra page.
You can also add `!` into the optional placement specifier of the `table` environment, i.e. `\begin{table}[!ht]`, to overwrite/ignore this settings for the specific table.

Answer (score 3):

This line will solve your problem:

```
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.8}
```

If it is a double column paper, you may need this instead/as well:

```
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{0.8}
```