# Use placeins for subsections

Tags: floats, positioning

I would like to place figures in my document in certain `subsections`. Normally I would achieve this with `float` using `[H]`. But this would mean, that the figures are at fixed points in my text and sometimes this just doesn't look good.

I already found this question: [How do I ensure that figures appear in the section they're associated with?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279/how-do-i-ensure-that-figures-appear-in-the-section-theyre-associated-with)

How can I tell LaTeX use `subsections` as `float barriers` instead of `sections`.

Comment: My eyes keep wanting to pronounce *placeins* like *proteins*. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `placeins` package, with the `section` option, redefines `\section`. You might succeed with `\usepackage{placeins}` and

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\subsection\expandafter
    {\expandafter\@fb@secFB\subsection}%
  \newcommand\@fb@secFB{\FloatBarrier
    \gdef\@fb@afterHHook{\@fb@topbarrier \gdef\@fb@afterHHook{}}}%
  \g@addto@macro\@afterheading{\@fb@afterHHook}%
  \gdef\@fb@afterHHook{}%
}
\makeatother
```

This will do the same the `section` option does, but for `\subsection` instead of `\section`.

Untested. On a side note, *don't* use `[H]`: it's a sure cause for problems in placing floats.

Comment: This solves my problem with the positioning, but it changes all my section/subsection numbering.

Comment: @DaniWho Sorry, I missed doing a change. Fixed. The `\section` command should have been `\subsection`.

Comment: Note that this solution eliminates the `\FloatBarrier` in `\section`! It can happen that a float ends *between* a section title and its first subsection. To avoid this, you need to redefine **both**.

Comment: this can clearly be used also for subsubsection

Comment: It produces this error:
Command \@fb@secFB already defined. \begin{document}

Comment: @skan That happens if you call `\usepackage[section]{placeins}`. The answer tells you to call `\usepackage{placeins}`.

Comment: And what's the difference between you answer and Oberdiek's?

Comment: @skan I wrote it first

Answer (score 44):

If `\subsection` implicitely calls `\FloatBarrier`, then also `\section` should do it:

```
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
```

The following adds the implicit `\FloatBarrier` to `\subsection`:

```
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\expandafter\subsection\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\@fb@secFB\subsection
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Don't you mean "If `\section` implicitely calls `\FloatBarrier`, then also `\subsection` should do it"?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever No.

Comment: I'm wondering whether or not we actually need all these expandafter commands...

Comment: @LucEvertzen You will get an infinite recursion without `\expandafter`, when `\subsection` is called.