# Use placeins for paragraphs

Tags: floats, placeins

I know how to use placeins to [prevent floats from floating into different `subsection`s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118662/use-placeins-for-subsections). The same solution seems to work for `subsubsection`s but not for `paragraph`s. Is there any way I can prevent figures from floating across `paragraph`s?

Comment: you can use the package's `\FloatBarrier` command anywhere

Comment: I know. What I want is for that command to be applied to every `\paragraph`, just as it is applied to every `\subsection` in the linked thread.

Comment: `\let\oldparagraph\paragraph\def\paragraph{\FloatBarrier\oldparagraph}` ?

Comment: do you have very long \paragraph texts? if not, it hardly gives latex any chance to float the floats at all? Do you want floats rather than just fixed images and tables?