# Ensure a table or figure is in the right (sub)section

Tags: floats, positioning

First of all, related: [How to fix table position](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9485/how-to-fix-table-position)

Here it is said how to fix a position to the exact place you position it in the latex document. I was wondering if it is also possible to float it within a `\section` or `\subsection`, but keep it fixed to that (sub)section. In other words: let it float within only a certain (sub)section and not the entire document, so I am certain table X will end up somewhere in section X and table Y will end up somewhere in section Y.

**EDIT** The question was already answered here: [Use placeins for subsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118662/use-placeins-for-subsections)

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is your question any different from the one you are linking to? imho, it already answers your question, too. If not, then you will need to provide an MWE to illustrate what exactly you want to achieve. Actually, do so anyway, as it's good practice on this site.

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell, it tells how to fix it for example between two paragraphs or lines of text. It doesn't tell how I can let the floating work within one (sub) section, but that the table of (sub)section X, does not end up in (sub)section Y. That is what I am after: making it 'fixed' to a (sub)section, but let it float within that section.. if that makes any sense :)

Comment: I editted  /reprhased the question

Comment: Do you know about the `placeins` package and its `\FloatBarrier` declaration?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @GuM. I editted the question with the place it has been answered. I tried looking for an answer, but obviously did not try hard enough. With 'placeins package' I got to the right thread.

Comment: @GuM I should have mentioned it explicitly, but basically, that was my point. All the necessary information, including how to use placeins and FloatBarrier is explained in the linked question. This is why I didn't understand what was asked, that wasn't already answered ;)

Comment: @thymaro you're right that it is answered there as well, but I did not realise that it explicitly addressed my question. The second link (see the EDIT), addresses the issue explicitly. Thank you both.

Comment: My point was: it uses jargon I was unfamiliar with and so I did not understand it would solve my problem.

Comment: To @thymaro as well as to the OP: I must admit that I didn’t try very hard, but I too was not able to find a question/answer mentioning the `\FloatBarrier` command to point to as a question of which this one is a duplicate, although I knew that there *must* be at least one!  Maybe that, now that you have found it, this one can be closed as a duplicate.  I’m taking care of this, as a user with enough rep to do so.

Comment: @Anonymous oh, yes, that was the problem. I should have noticed it as it happens to me as well, that I read over the answer to my question, because I don't recognize it as what I'm looking for.