# How to automatically put FloatBarrier before and after each section

Tags: floats, sectioning, placeins

I am looking for a command like:

```
\alwaysFloatBarrier
```

Such that whenever I write a normal section or subsection or subsubsection:

```
\section{Example 1}

\subsection{Example 2}

\subsubsection{Example 3}
```

They get automatically converted to:

```
\FloatBarrier
\section{Example 1}
\FloatBarrier

\FloatBarrier
\subsection{Example 2}
\FloatBarrier

\FloatBarrier
\subsubsection{Example 3}
\FloatBarrier
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I can understand you desire not to let floats cross section-level divisions. But subsection-level and subsubsection-level divisions too? Please clarify you use case.

Comment: @Mico yes I need not crossing subsection-level and subsubsection-level divisions because my use case is very long and detailed technical reports with many graphs.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your use case in more detail. It helped me formulate an answer, which I posted a few minutes ago.

Comment: I don't think it does you any good to issue `\FloatBarrier` instructions *after* `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve your objective by loading the `placeins` package (for the `\FloatBarrier` macro) along with the `etoolbox` package (for the `\pretocmd`  macro) and issuing the instructions

```
\pretocmd{\section}{\FloatBarrier}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsection}{\FloatBarrier}{}{}
\pretocmd{\subsubsection}{\FloatBarrier}{}{}
```

in the preamble. If you need this in macro form, you could write

```
\newcommand\alwaysFloatBarrier{%
   \pretocmd{\section}{\FloatBarrier}{}{}%
   \pretocmd{\subsection}{\FloatBarrier}{}{}%
   \pretocmd{\subsubsection}{\FloatBarrier}{}{}%
}
```

and then issue the instruction `\alwaysFloatBarrier`.

Comment: should the second and third ones be `subsection` and  `subsubsection`?

Comment: @Caridorc - Absolutely! Let me fix that right away.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mico for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You have not said but I assume you mean the command from the `placeins` package, in which case `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` does what you need.

A lat this dos what is asked for in the title, for sections, it does not automatically do the same for subsections, but forcing page breaks at the lower order headings isn't usually desirable.

Comment: I wonder if you didn't answer too quickly. IIRC the option `section` adds `Floatbarrier` to section only and not to subsection, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes I meant the `placeins` package, thanks a lot for your answer. I also found another relevant question for this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118662/use-placeins-for-subsections

Comment: @Jhor well I answered the question in the title, you are right that doesn't actually match the example code. I'll add a clarifying note...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, sorry I wanted to avoid an overly long title