# Picture from another subsection appears in another

Tags: tables, floats, errors, lyx, subsection

Im trying to put my pictures accordingly to the content of my subsection but until one part where i had a figure in 2.1 subsection appears after the content as i want but my 2.2 subsection figures pop right below of the figure before also before its subsection

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community The first sentence is a bit of a run on, but it's clear enough.  Unfortunately, I don't know lyx.  Are you able to make your figures non-floating?  Floating is the source of your problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on where it says "Float: figure" in LyX, then click on "Settings" and then change "Placement Settings" to "Custom". Then check the box that you want. However, even if you click on "Here definitely" I'm not sure it's guaranteed to be there. In that case, you might need a custom LyX module or to use ERT.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually seeing the code it is difficult to guess if something else, besides the "normal" floating behaviour of figures, is going on. However, have a look at the [`placeins`](https://ctan.org/pkg/placeins) package, which is supposed to prevent floating from one section to the next. The documentation also points out how its float barriers may be adapted to specific toc-levels (since you are looking at floating between subsections). How to do that will likely depend on the document class you are using and the way it defines its sectioning commands.
See also: [Use placeins for subsections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118662/use-placeins-for-subsections)