# Insert two pdf pages at the bottom

Tags: pdfpages

I would like to insert a pdf document of 2 pages in my document only on the bottom half part of the page. Using the [pdfpages](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) package with the command

```
\includepdf[nup=2x1,pages=-]{<mypdf>}
```

place the 2 pages side by side but half of my page is "lost". I would like to be able to use the upper half of my page as I want, and insert this 2 pages in the bottom half.

Here is an illustration of the result that I would like

[image]

Any help would be much appreciate.

Comment: I think using `\includegraphics` twice inside a table would do it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but I havn't succed to place it side by side using all the length of the page. Would you mind giving me a code for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can place the pages using `\includegraphics` and specify the `page`s separately:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}

\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{.7}% Allow up to 70% of bottom-floats to be on a page
\begin{document}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-7]

\begin{figure}[b]
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,page=1]{lipsum50}%
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,page=2]{lipsum50}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[8-14]

\end{document}
```

We ensure each page fits exactly within the text width (setting their widths to be `.5\linewidth`). Depending on the page geometry, you may have to update `\bottomfraction` as well, allowing a certain portion of the page to be taken up by floats. See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764) and/or [How can I get the figures not to be pushed to the end of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11382/5764)

`lipsum50.pdf` is a document that just has `\lipsum[1-50]` in it.

Comment: I didn't know that `\includgraphics` accepts a `page` option, and have resorted to pdfTeX primitives to achieve this in the past. AFAICT, the `page` option is undocumented, at least in `grfguide.pdf`. Perhaps I am looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Talk to David in chat. [I've started a conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33969097#33969097).

Comment: Does it make sense to also use `keepaspectratio`?

Comment: @StrongBad: Without specifying an additional `height` parameter, the aspect ratio will be preserved. You can add it, if you want.

Answer (score 4):

This solution embeds two `minipage`s into a floating `picture`-environment. 
 Instead of defining the width of the included pictures (i.e. pdf) this solution use the "updated" `linewidth` of the minipages. You can refer to Werner's approach for lighter solution.

(Note that `\fbox` are here just for making pages boundaries more obvious. You can/should of course remove it in your final document.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \begin{figure}[!b]
        \begin{minipage}[c]{.5\linewidth}
            \fbox{\includegraphics[page=1, width=\linewidth]{pdf-to-be-included.pdf}}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill
        \begin{minipage}[c]{.5\linewidth}
            \fbox{\includegraphics[page=2, width=\linewidth]{pdf-to-be-included.pdf}}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Zanzi Note that a `.5\linewidth` minipage is a bit wider that 50% of the `\linewidth` due to inner/outer sep. Thus, the embedded pdf encroachs upon margin. So go for Werner's solution!

Comment: Yes, I figured it out that. Your solution was almost perfect.