# Why is one of my figures pushed to the right?

Tags: graphics

This is the image I am trying to insert:

[image: Image to insert]

This is the relevant code used to insert it into my `.tex` file with `\documentclass{article}`. Previous line:

```
where \textit{tooffsets[i + 1]} depends on \textit{toffsets[i]}.
```

and then the code to insert the image:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphics/cpu.PNG}
\caption{Visualizing sequential CPU algorithm}
\end{figure}
```

I am using `\usepackage{float}` to enable `[H]`.

But it is not being rendered properly in the PDF:

[image: misaligned document]

In that the image is pushed to the right, appears above the text which comes before it in the code and there is no caption.

The other places where I have inserted images similarly, do not have alignment issues.

Related questions:

- [How can I get the figures not to be pushed to the end of the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11366/how-can-i-get-the-figures-not-to-be-pushed-to-the-end-of-the-document)
- [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

Comment: Could you give a bit more context? Because if I just enter the code you give here, it formats as you want it to format, so there is something else going wrong.

Comment: With provided information is not possible to reproduce your problem. Your code is just fine. My test: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Graphics/cpu.PNG}
\caption{Visualizing sequential CPU algorithm}
\end{figure}    
\end{document} `

Comment: Most of the time, this sort of problem has to do with white space in the image itself.  Try `\fbox{\includegraphics{...}}` and see how big is really is.